# How to uninstall Atom text editor on Linux?

Tags: atom-editor

i was reading the documentation looking for a way to cleanly uninstall Atom from my linux OS, but i didn't find anything related.

Is there a set of directories to delete? or maybe an script to run?

Thanks for the attention

Comment: I posted a [Windows version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29606833/2327328) of this question.

Comment: As with any Linux software: It depends on how you installed it in the first place.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I have posted the same question in the Github Project Repository and this is the complete answer: https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/2195#issuecomment-42917489

The commands to execute are:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/atom
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/apm
rm -rf ~/atom
rm -rf ~/.atom
rm -rf ~/.config/Atom-Shell
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/atom/
```

Comment: The directory name under ~/.config is not Atom-Shell anymore. Replace it with Atom please

Comment: +1 @HalilBİLGİN (at least for ubuntu). Still, to remove the application from Unity's list, I had to do this as well: $ sudo rm /usr/local/share/applications/atom.desktop

Comment: FYI, mine was installed under /usr/share/atom, so try there if the above commands don't work

Comment: I had to run `sudo apt-get purge atom` command to cleanly remove the app from Ubuntu 16.04 Unity desktop.

Answer (score 86):

For Ubuntu 14.04 & Ubuntu 18.04, use the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove atom
```

Comment: I upvoted this during usage of Ubuntu 14.04, and this was the only asnwer that worked on Ubuntu 18.04 as well.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 20.04 too

Answer (score 41):

If you installed atom using the .deb package, you can remove it using this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove atom
```

If you want to remove any config directories, you can use this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge atom
```

Answer (score 22):

Atom may also be installed as a Snap. You can find out by using:

```
$ sudo snap list
```

If you see it in the list you can remove it with:

```
$ sudo snap remove atom
```

For more on snaps:
https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/snappy

Answer (score 5):

In RHEL (I guess also Fedora/CentOS), just type: `yum erase atom`

Comment: In Fedora 25 and greater it is `sudo dnf erase atom`, as `yum` got depreciated here.

Answer (score 4):

**on Ubuntu** (15.04): 
after installing the `.deb` from *atom.io*, I found the package available under the *Ubuntu Software center*.

Comment: This doesn't apply for Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3):

I would use simply

`sudo apt remove --purge atom`

since it is also suggested in the (un-official) installation page [here](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/08/05/install-atom-text-editor-ubuntu-16-04/)

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 14.04, with Atom 1.0, I didn't find anything under `/usr/local/bin/`.

However, the install was at `/usr/share/atom/`, which I deleted.

Comment: This technique is not good, because there are other folders that contain files for Atom. If you download .rpm version of Atom and extract it, you will see that usr/local/bin is one of directories where you want your files, but there are 3 more directories where Atom will save files.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Atom by .deb, then you can just remove by:

```
sudo dpkg -r atom
```

Answer (score 0):

In fedora,it can be removed by:

```
sudo dnf remove atom
```