# How to uninstall Atom text editor on Windows?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, uninstallation, atom-editor

I installed the text editor [Atom](https://atom.io/) for Windows with the installer package ([blog post with details](http://blog.atom.io/2014/12/10/a-windows-installer-and-updater.html)). Note that I did **not** use the old way of installing, with [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/).

When I wanted to uninstall, I didn't see any uninstall program. When I went to the "Remove programs" window, the uninstall option was invalid.

[image]

**How can I uninstall it?**

I found the same question for [Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23621181/2327328) and [Mac](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-completely-uninstall-atom-for-mac/9084/12), but so far no details for Windows.

Comment: What did you get when you tried the steps in the link you provided?

Comment: The link is for Linux, I posted as a reference and self-answered below for Windows.

Comment: Right, never mind. ^.^

Comment: +1 deleting Atom from my computer is the greatest decision I've made. Now I am more highly productive than ever before! Thank you!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You have to remove some folders and then Atom should be removed from your computer:

Delete these folders:

```
C:\Users\UserName\.atom
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\atom
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Atom
```

And this shortcut file:

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\GitHub, Inc\Atom
```

---

To remove the PATH entry, <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, "Edit the System Environment Variables" and select "Environment Variables..." button on the bottom right

[image]

Highlight "PATH" on the top end hit "Edit..."

[image]

Then remove this entry:

```
C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\atom\bin
```

and click OK.

[image]

---

In order to remove the context menu commands you'll need to remove these keys from your registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.apmrc
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open File in Atom
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Open Folder in Atom
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Open Folder in Atom
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\Background\shell\Open Folder in Atom
```

Comment: Good God... what's the point of even having an uninstaller, when that much crud is left behind?

Comment: Holy cow. Look at the procedure on how to delete an application. Much wow. This is my gripe on the so called "Open-Source" applications. It sucks really.

Comment: that post really helped, but I couldn't find "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.apmrc" so when i right click on a non folder/file there is still "Open with Atom" which does not make sense, even if the program would be still installed. Thanks for not giving us an uninstaller, github!

Comment: For me installed didn't show any errors, but left files mentioned in answer and *HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.atom/config* key

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to run AtomSetup.exe again to reinstall then immediately uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE of answer philishem:

If you use **CCleaner** the path registry will be delete if the program's broken.
And you can delete the item *ATOM*  on list program available.

The paths indicated by ***Philishem*** still exists but there is one other on:

```
C:\Users\mcianfarani\AppData\Roaming\Atom
```

It seems that have information cache and cookie:
[image]

P.S. The process used from **ATOM** are :

- **UPDATE**
- **ATOM**

If you can't delete the directory, go on `Task Manager` -> `Process` -> and broke these!