# Atom cant find any packages

Tags: atom-editor

I noticed, that since a couple of weeks or something like that, I can not install new packages to atom. Typing anything into the search bar results in this error:

```
i.filter is not a function
[object Object]
```

How can I fix this error?

I am using Atom 1.49.0 and MacOS 10.15.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also tried uninstalling the app with the standard unistall and also with [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606833/how-to-uninstall-atom-text-editor-on-windows) and reinstalling it but the on-site search didnt currently work either.

Comment: sometimes it does sometimes it doesnt as of writing this comment